# Cannot start WEBrick server. Mysql2 `require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I have installed a fresh install of Ruby / Rails on an clean Windows 8 install and amy getting errors when trying to start the WEBrick server. Have searched for an answer but cant find one.

Error as below:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Brendon/Sites/quote/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bundler to install the gem first.

Either do:

```
gem install mysql2
```

or

```
cd /my/rails/project && bundle install
```

*note: the mysql2 gem is a [expletive] to install... best of luck*